# processStartInfo run exe?

Tags: monitoring, processstartinfo

when you invoke :

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("someExecutable.exe");
```

Does this actually run the `someExecutable.exe` or does it just monitor that? I am essentially seeing if this can be used to read output from an already running exe or if it will call the exe.

I am trying to find a way to just monitor and record a few values from an already running exe.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this actually run the someExecutable.exe or dies it just monitor that?

The answer is *neither ... nor*! The [MSDN article about the ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states:

> You can use the ProcessStartInfo class for better control over the process you start. You must at least set the FileName property, either manually or using the constructor.

and also

> ProcessStartInfo is used together with the Process component. When you start a process using the Process class, you have access to process information in addition to that available when attaching to a running process.

Using the *ProcessStartInfo* class you can neither start, nor monitor a process.

**However** depending on what you need to monitor (for example the output of the executable) you can use the *ProcessStartInfo* class to redirect the ouput of the process you are going to start programmatically. In order to do that you need to set the [RedirectStandardOutput property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the *ProcessStartInfo* class. So you need the class in order to allow/configure process monitoring assuming you will start the process programmatically.

The commented MSDN example to clarify my answer:

```
// Process is NOT started yet! process name is set
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("IExplore.exe");
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
// Process is NOT started yet! process object is initialized with the process info like filename and so on. 
Process.Start(startInfo);
// Process is NOT started yet! process arguments are set. 
// The equivalent command line in a shell would be: c:\>IExplore.exe www.northwindtraders.com ENTER is NOT pressed yet!
startInfo.Arguments = "www.northwindtraders.com";
// NOW the process is executed/started => 
// c:\>IExplore.exe www.northwindtraders.com <= ENTER is pressed, process is started/running!
// c:\>
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: I know about the properties, but what I am asking is if I specifically set the FileName property does that mean it is going to run the exe?

Comment: @user3174707: **No** - setting the FileName property is not going to run the exe! I have added a commented example to clarify my answer.